# Customizing CKEditor

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, ckeditor

I'm building a site with Perch Cms (really neat, check it out!), and now I'm trying to customize the ckeditor I just installed.

What I'm trying to to is basicly just to restrict the formatting options and so on in the editor.

I've managed to find the config.js file in CKE's root folder.

The changes so far, which at least make some difference:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{   
    config.toolbar_Full = [
        ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord'],
        ['Undo', 'Redo'],
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Format']
    ];      
};
```

But how can I specify which heading tags that are allowed?

Comment: So you don't have 8 different heading to choose from. Just trying to make it a little less confusing for the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3'; in this case only p,h1,h2,h3 will be shown in format dropdown.